# Adding Hyphen in data-value string dynamically jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a page with a simple UL that's supposed to be populated at runtime via AJAX calls and JSON responses.

```
$(".select-brands").append("<li data-value=" + manufacturerName + ">" + manufacturer + "</li>");
```

After this i'm using that data-value attribute in order to scroll to the element of the same name as the one the user selected in a different selection box. So when they select the Harley Davidson picture the jQuery will look in the  for an element with

```
data-value="HARLEY-DAVIDSON"
```

However the result is not what i expected, instead of that data-value i'm instead getting elements like this

```
<li data-value="HARLEY" davidson="">HARLEY DAVIDSON</li>
```

How can i make it so that i can select the elements based on this name? can it be done via the text inside of the li tags?

```
// Get corresponding brand on list by custom data-value attribute //
var listBrand = $('li[data-value="'+ selectedBrand.toUpperCase() +'"]');
var parent    = $('#brands-select');
var index     = listBrand.index();

parent.animate({
        scrollTop: $('#brands-select li:nth-child('+ index +')').position().top - $('#brands-select li:first').position().top
}, 'slow');
```

That's the code i use in order to scroll to the element selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".select-brands").append("<li data-value=" + manufacturerName + ">" + manufacturer + "</li>");
```

You don't have quotes around the attribute name. You should do it like this:

```
$(".select-brands").append("<li data-value='" + manufacturerName + "'>" + manufacturer + "</li>");
```

With quotes.

Without them, it gets parsed as two separate attributes, like this: `<li data-value=HARLEY-DAVIDSON>`, because the hyphen gets ignored.

Comment: Almost perfect.. IMO, you should add the reason for _break_ in attribute...